# How do you use PdfSharp.Extensions for extracting images?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am trying to extract/export an image from a PDF file and then save it to a Jpeg file using `PdfSharp`. I have tried the sample code provided in the PdfSharp web site unsuccessfully.

However, I found at https://github.com/gheeres/PDFSharp.Extensions sample code which is supposed to do the task.  The sample code contains the line

```
For Each image As Image In page.GetImages()
```

My Visual Studio 2012 tells me that `GetImages` is not part of `PdfSharp`.

*How is this `PdfSharp.Extension` to be used?*

I have imported all of the following:

```
Imports System.IO,
Imports System.Drawing.Image,
Imports PdfSharp,
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.IO,
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced,
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfItem,
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging,
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not look hard enough. The NuGet web site shows how to install the Extensions. I did and then the code worked just fine. My apologies for asking the question.